# What do I do wrong when install OpenKiwi?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I tried to work with [OpenKiwi](https://unbabel.github.io/OpenKiwi/) to Anaconda3
and after installation (pip install openkiwi)
I execute following code
(I do this because I want to create [openkiwi vocabulary](https://unbabel.github.io/OpenKiwi/_modules/kiwi/data/vocabulary.html)) :

```
import warnings
from collections import defaultdict
import torchtext
from kiwi.constants import PAD, START, STOP, UNALIGNED, UNK, UNK_ID
```

And than I have an error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ea850b280bef> in <module>
      4 import torchtext
      5 
----> 6 from kiwi.constants import PAD, START, STOP, UNALIGNED, UNK, UNK_ID

ImportError: cannot import name 'UNK_ID' from 'kiwi.constants' (C:\Users\Mike\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kiwi\constants.py)
```

Anaconda3 has following versions: >!

- pytorch-lightning: 1.7.6
- pytorch-nlp: 0.5.0
- torch: 1.4.0
- torch metrics   0.9.3
- torch: text 0.13.1
- transformers: 3.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNK_ID` is no longer a constant in the latest version of OpenKiwi. That second link shows some code targeting version 1.4 or so, while OpenKiwi is at version 2.1 now. Just drop the `UNK_ID` from the `import` line, and replace the one in the code with `0`.